# What is this f-string syntax error (unmatched '[')?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am trying to build a basic text-based weather application for a project at school. I am new to programming and have run into an error in my code. Essentially, whenever I try to use an f-string and index a dictionary, I run into an error. I could just not use the f-string, but I'm wondering why it doesn't work.

Here's an example of the error I'm running into.

```
weather = {"day1": {"temp": "20.4", "condition" : "Partly cloudy"}, "day2": {"temp": "24.3", "condition" : "Sunny"}}

day_1_temp = weather["day1"]["temp"]
print(f"{day_1_temp}") # <-- works perfectly fine

print(f"Day 1 temperature: {weather["day1"]["temp"]}") # <-- gives an error:  SyntaxError: f-string: unmatched '['
```

I can't really tell what the problem is by looking at it; the '[' looks matched to me.

Comment: alternate between `'` and `"`: `f"Day 1 temperature: {weather['day1']['temp']}"`

Comment: Or use Python 3.12: https://docs.python.org/3.13/whatsnew/3.12.html#whatsnew312-pep701.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print( f"Day 1 temperature: {weather['day1']['temp']}")
```

I replaced the double quotes with single ones

Comment: hey Potato, there's already answer there related to f string stuff.